# How conversation of momentum is ensured in (Projected) Gauss-Seidel constrain solver

Tags: linear-algebra, game-physics, physics-engine

I was reading paper about [Position Based Dynamics](https://matthias-research.github.io/pages/publications/posBasedDyn.pdf) to solve linear (elastic) constrains between bodies in a physics game engine. There is stressed that conservation of linear momentum must be ensured by displacing the bodies (end-points of the constraining bond) by displacement inversely proportional to mass of the points (as shown on Figure 2).

Now I'm reading a different paper [Vivace: a Practical Gauss-Seidel Method for Stable Soft Body Dynamics](https://mfratarcangeli.github.io/publication/sigasia2016/). Here they show that much more efficient algorithm can be implemented using Gauss-Seidel parallelized on GPU using red-black coloring.

How I understand [Gauss-Seidel Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Seidel_method#Algorithm) in the context of points connected by rigid/elastic sticks can be expressed by following pseudocode:

```py
    repeat until convergence:
        for all points i:
            displacement_i = 0
            for all points j bonded to i by a stick with relaxed lenght L_ij:
               d = position_i - position_j
               l = |d|        # length of the stick
               h = d/|d|      # normalized direction of the stick 
               dl = L_ij - l  # how much the stick needs to be elongated/shortened  
               displacement_i += h * dl
            position_i += displacement_i
```

What I don't understand: when I do update position of the point **i** by Gauss-Seidel (in the outer for loop), it moves the point i asymmetrically to satisfy the constrain, while it does not move the neighboring points to which it is connected (i.e. it does not exert the **recoil** according to [3rd Newton Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_laws_of_motion#Third_law)). Therefore the result will depend very much on the order in which I update the point positions.

If I choose the order badly, it can easily happen that I displace the heavy points a lot and displace a light points a little. For example consider that I have just 2 points connected by one stick (`mass_1 >> mass_2`). According to the algorithm above I solve the constrain in 1 step by displacing `point_1` so that it is exactly at distance `l=L_12` from `point_2`. However such solution would be unphysical because it will move the heavy point and not move the light point. The center of mass will move a lot, and conservation of the linear momentum will be violated.